# Card pile with prev next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Card pile with prev next](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bQKNLa)

```
<ul id="deck">
    <li class="card"><img src="http://goodlogo.com/images/logos/small/starbucks_coffee_logo_2413.gif" alt="1" /></li>
    <li class="card"><img src="http://i1.wp.com/carlogos.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Volkswagen.gif?resize=100%2C100" alt="2" /></li>
    <li class="card"><img src="http://goodlogo.com/images/logos/small/dell_logo_3529.gif" alt="3" /></li>
    <li class="card"><img src="http://i1.wp.com/carlogos.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/BMW.gif?resize=100%2C100" alt="4" /></li>
    <li class="card"><img src="http://i1.wp.com/carlogos.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Mazda.gif?resize=100%2C100" alt="5" /></li>
    <li class="card"><img src="http://i1.wp.com/carlogos.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Saab.gif?resize=100%2C100" alt="6" /></li>
    <li class="card"><img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/lego/images/2/2d/LEGO_logo.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130601154044" alt="7" /></li>
    <li class="card"><img src="https://g.twimg.com/Twitter_logo_blue.png" alt="8" /></li>
</ul>

<button>Prev</button>
<button>Next</button>
```

This is the fork of a pen that slide cards clicking over them. I would like to edit it so that I can go back and forward between cards clicking on 2 buttons "prev" and "next".

Could someone help me with the code, how to edit it and explain me?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are few methods for inserting.
For `prev` you can use `Node.insertBefore`.
First argument is an element to paste, second is element before which you want to paste. So you want to paste last element before first:

```
function prev() {
    let parent = document.querySelector("#deck");
    parent.insertBefore(parent.lastElementChild, parent.firstElementChild);
}
```

For `next` you can use `Node.appendChild` method, which paste element as a last child element. So you paste first child element from `deck` and append it to it as last:

```
function next() {
    let parent = document.querySelector("#deck");
    parent.appendChild(parent.firstElementChild);
}
```

Or you can use `insertBefore` method again with `null` second argument. When second argument is `null`, it works like `appendChild`, inserting it as last child:

```
function next() {
    let parent = document.querySelector("#deck");
    parent.insertBefore(parent.firstElementChild, null);
}
```

More information on mozilla's developer website
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and reply, I've updated the PEN but maybe I've done something wrong. It seems not working, maybe I'm missing something... No transition effect are applied. MaybeI should edit the JS code incapsulating your scripts?

Comment: At first, you make animation callbacks to work on `first` element's `click` event listener.
You should add such listenter on `prev`/`next` buttons, to make it work on button click.

Comment: Second problem - in your `transitionEnded` function you move around values of images' attribute `src`. But functions `prev` and `next` move elements themself. It significly different behaviour.
If you add `prev` or `next` functions call on click and leave `transitionEnded` as it is, you will move elements and `src` values. So it will look like double change - from 1st to 3rd, instead from 1st to 2nd.
You should rewrite function `transitionEnded` to just call `next` instead of `src` round robin.

Comment: And be careful with your `deck` queue. It is assigned on `exec` function call, not click. It means it will have the same order on each click.
You will "remember" sequence of elements in `card` variable. It's better, if it will work directly with `deck.childNodes` every time.
`function transitionEnded(deck) { console.log('transition ended'); deck.classList.remove('sliding'); next(); }`

Comment: Thanks for you kind comments but I cannot let it work, could you please help me editing the codepen to make it work as expected? Really really really appreciated any help!